# How can I get a non-blocking infinite loop in a Kotlin Actor?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I would like to consume some stream-data using Kotlin actors
I was thinking to put my consumer inside an actor, while it polls in an infinite loop `while(true)`. Then, when I decide, I send a message to stop the consumer.

Currently I have this:

```
while(true) {
     for (message in channel){    <--- blocked in here, waiting
            when(message) {
                is MessageStop -> consumer.close()
                else -> {}
        }
    }

    consumer.poll()
}
```

**The problem**
The problem with this is that it only runs when I send a message to the actor, so my consumer is not polling the rest of the time because channel is blocking waiting to receive the next message

Is there any alternative?, someone with the same issue?, or something similar to actors but not blocked by channel in Kotlin?

Comment: Could [kotlin flow](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/flow.html#flows) do what you want?

Comment: out of curiousity... what is `consumer` here? is this all wrapped inside an `actor`-call? and/or how is the `channel` created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the channel is *just* a Channel (https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/-channel/index.html) you can first check if the channel is empty and if so start your polling. Otherwise handle the messages.

E.g.

```
while(true) {

    while (channel.isNotEmpty()) {
        val message = channel.receive()
        when(message) {
            is MessageStop -> consumer.close()
            else -> {}
        }
     }

    consumer.poll()
}
```

Comment: for (message in channel) is more simple

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used AKKA with Kotlin, I'm finding much easier this way

Comment: this does not really answer your question... if this should answer "is there any alternative", then it would be nice to see, how the code looks now...  maybe this also helps to understand what you were trying to accomplish and may also lead to the actual solution of your stated problem...

Comment: make sense, apologies. I accepted a proper answer

Answer (score 0):

You should use `postDelayed()`, for example:

```
final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // your code here
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000)
    }
}
```

You can change `1000` with the the millisecond delay you want. Also I highly recommend to put your code inside a thread (if you are not already have) to prevent ANR (App Not Responding)